# UIButton never fires off code in Action

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have the following screen:

[image]

The X is the image of a `UIButton`, I have add the appropriate action to the button. Yet when I click on the button it never fires off the code in the action.

Here is some code:

```
 @IBAction func CloseProfilePage(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.removeAnimate();    
    }
```

This is the code that is used to launch the view controller seen:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedAppointment = self.dayDatasource!.appointmentAtIndex(indexPath.item);
        let profilePageViewController = ProfilePageViewController.init(withAppointment: selectedAppointment);

        profilePageViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(profilePageViewController.view)
        profilePageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    }
```

The button is definitely connected in the xib to the action:

[image]

When I check in the view hierachy, there isn't anything else on top of the button that would prevent the button but registering clicks. I'm assuming here that the imageView in the `UIButton` is clickable as its part of the button iteself.

[image]

The X in the image is not an image view I added, it is the image view that comes with the `UIButton`. With that said I've also resorted to the following:

```
self.profilePageClosePopUpButton.imageView?.userInteractionEnabled = true;
```

Still the button remains unclickable. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is that a CollectionViewCell?

Comment: No, I select a collection view cell, which opens the viewController

Comment: Have you tried printing something to make sure the issue is with the button rather than the function called when the button is pressed?

Comment: Yes, it still doesn't log anything

Comment: You may want to try deleting it and adding another one - this is very unusual

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `IBAction` connection and reconnecting it?

Comment: what about setting image like button.setImage method , try once

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari That shouldn't really make a difference: it's more likely a connection issue

Comment: Try changing `AnyObject` to `UIButton`

Comment: Increase frame size make fix your issue

Comment: Try to set in the view container clipToSubview

Comment: Check the frame of profilePageViewController once, if that goes wrong then its sub views will not function. You can check it with simply assigning background colour to it.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for trying to help out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It pains me to say this but I'm only writing a solution here just in case someone in the future struggles with the same issue and maybe this post could help them.

In the view, seen in the image below, I had some how unintentionally switched off User Interaction Enabled in interface builder. Because this was off, all other children didn't have interaction enabled on them and hence why the button was not clickable...

[image]

Moral of the story is, check your parent views and make sure their user interaction is enabled as well.